# ASP.Net WebApi is not serializing bool if set to true

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net, default-value

I have the following model:

```
public class DocumentViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long? ParentFolderId { get; set; }
    public bool IsFolder { get; set; }
    public bool IsImage { get; set; }
}
```

and the following API Controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetChildren(long jobId, long folderId)
{            
    using (var model = DatabaseHelper.GetModel())
    {
        var accessLevel = MembershipHelper.GetLoggedInAccessLevel(model);
        List<DocumentViewModel> documents = DocumentHelper.GetDocumentsForMobile(model, jobId, folderId, accessLevel).ToList();

        return this.Request.CreateResponse(
            HttpStatusCode.OK,
            new { data = documents });
    }
}
```

The problem is that IsFolder and IsImage are missing from the json when I review this in Fiddler when they are set to false.  They show up fine when they are set to true.

I suspect this is because .Net thinks true is the default value, and excludes fields where the value is the same as the default.

How do I tell .Net to ALWAYS include this value, regardless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Register` method of the `WebApiConfig` class (located in the `App_Start` folder) try adding this line:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling =
                                   Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Include;
```

This should force Web Api to include default values if it isn't already.

**EDIT**

If you're using an older version of Web API that does not have a WebApiConfig, you can also do this in the `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
var jsonSettings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
jsonSettings.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Include;
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that I have a WebApiConfig class.  How would I add this?